# Alternative to escape slashes in search and replace for long strings

Tags: search, regular-expression, replace

Is there any alternative in vim search and replace for strings, than having to escape every special character in string.

For example, If I want to match following string and replace with something

```
[ERROR] Login unsucessful
```

Then I have to do

```
:%s/\[ERROR\]\ Login\ unsucessful/something/g
```

And it becomes lot more uglier and painful for complex strings containing lot of special characters

I would like to do something like

```
:%s/"[ERROR] Login unsucessful"/something/g
```

which would avoid all escaping.
Is there any feature like this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `very-nomagic` switch. See `:h \V` for details. This would give you `%s/\V[ERROR] Login unsuccessful/something/g`. There is also the `nomagic` switch `\M`, which is a lighter version of `\V` and does not seem to be widely used.

Also note that you don't have to escape spaces as you do in your example, even when not using `\V`.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I wanted. didn't get this on my google search, dunno why.

Comment: @MohitC I map `/` to `/\v` to enable "very magic" for most searches, so I have mapped `//` to `/` to start an unmodified search (useful for going through search history ignoring modifiers) and `/v/` to `/\V` to quickly turn off all magic for searching.

Comment: @MohitC In fact, my setup is more complicated than that, because I also use a plugin to use "very magic" as consistently as possible in all contexts. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23021259/1858225).

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to escape spaces. So this:

```
:%s/\[ERROR\]\ Login\ unsucessful/something/g
```

should actually be:

```
:%s/\[ERROR\] Login unsucessful/something/g
```

And, of course, you can enable *very nomagic* "mode" to make those special characters less special:

```
:%s/\V[ERROR] Login unsucessful/something/g
```

See `:help /magic`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the *nomagic* flags mention in other answers.

It is often the case that you don't need to be precise in your search string

For example, to match

```
[ERROR] Login unsucessful
```

You could use the expression

```
.ERROR. Login unsucessful
```

Obviously, you have to know that your data won't contain other strings, differing from your intended target but matching the expression.